# How do I create a Calendar View web part in SharePoint Designer 2013?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online

I've been trying to create a Calendar View web part using SharePoint Designer 2013 (I don't have Visual Studio) that I can upload to the Web Parts gallery and then from there use a 'code' snippet in a custom page I am building.

I have successfully managed to do this with several other web parts, but Calendar is proving quite tricky...

Is this indeed possible?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? How is this custom? You can create a new Calendar list, then add that as a ListView to any page / web part zone.

Comment: @Colbs, it's custom because I am using custom HTML components and Snippets to provide the Web Part functionality.  I don't seem to be able to create a Calendar Web Part that I am then able to upload to the gallery and hence use as a Snippet in my HTML.  What you say about being able to create a Calendar List and then add that to a Web Part Zone is true, however because the calendar is created as a "ListViewWebPart" and not an "XsltListViewWebPart" I can't add it to the Web Part gallery.